# ARIMAX - predict

Tags: forecasting, arima

I have the monthly number of patients in a psychiatric facility from Jan 2010 to Dec 2018 - the data shows a seasonal pattern.  I want to forecast the number of patients in the facility from Jan 2019 to Dec 2020 using seasonal ARIMAX, with the number of people receiving a mental health diagnosis as an exogenous variable. I have the monthly number of people receiving a mental health diagnosis from Jan 2010 to Dec 2018 also, but obviously I don't know what the future numbers will be out to Dec 2020.  So first I ran a seasonal ARIMA on the diagnosis data to get predictions from Jan 2019 to Dec 2020, and then I used these predictions for the exogenous variable component of the seasonal ARIMAX model (0,1,1)*(0,1,1)12 to forecast patient numbers at the psychiatric facility over the same time period.

Is this a reasonable approach to take?

What is the ARIMAX model actually doing with the exogenous variable predictions I feed into it? Is it treating them as known values (which they are not), or does it incorporate some measure of uncertainty for these in its predictions.

Answer (score 0):

In general your approach is correct. In terms of specifics when you build the arima model for your predictor it is wise to consider possible anomalies ala
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/09c4/ba8dd3cc88289caf18d71e8985bdd11ad21c.pdf . Secondly when you go to form the way X enters the model , you have to use pre-whitening to identify the contemporaneous and lag structure ala
https://web.archive.org/web/20160216193539/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75/
and [Transfer function in forecasting models - interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124533/transfer-function-in-forecasting-models-interpretation) . Finally you have touched on a third rail issue regarding the encoding/incorporating the uncertainty in the predictor INTO the uncertainty of the dependent variable. This is accomplished via boot-strapping the forecast probability distribution for the predictor AND the forecast probability distribution for the model errors. See https://autobox.com/cms/images/dllupdate/AutoboxUsersguide.pdf page 56 for a discussion for why and what you need to do. In terms of transparency , I have been involoved in implementing this very important feature that most analysts ignore .. but apparently not you and I and increasingly many others !

[Unable to remove seasonal flucatuations from NDVI data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383483/unable-to-remove-seasonal-flucatuations-from-ndvi-data/383484#383484) might help you further in understanding and explaining the ARIMAX model.

In specific when you feed the predictor into your model your software is most likely assuming a purely contemporaneous relationship. Not a good idea in general to assume this but some software places  the analytical burden is on you to pre-specify this.